# How can I make having different gravity object when every touch on object?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

My game has a ball and this ball has a gravity. I want to change ball's gravity when every touch on that. How can I do that? Here is my touchesBegan code :

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch:AnyObject in touches{
        let location = (touch as! UITouch).locationInNode(self)
        let nodeTouched = nodeAtPoint(location)
        let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
        //Detect if the ball is touched
        if(nodeTouched == ball){

            physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(-30, 30)
        }

}
```